# Stuck in void funtion, if conditions

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I stuck with this code. The question regarding to the code and my code are given below.  

QUESTION: Write a c program to input a number(Integer), If the input number is odd: print "(number) is an odd number",
 
If the input number is even,
multiply it by 2 if inserted number is 20 or between 10 and 20
multiply it by 3 if inserted number is 40 or between 30 and 40
multiply it by 4 if inserted number is 50 or between 40 and 50
Finally display the multiplied answer.

MY CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void todo1 ();

int main() {
    int i;
    printf("Enter Number:\t",i);
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if (i%2!=0) {
        printf("%d is an odd number",i);
    }
    else {
        todo1();
    }
    return 0; 
}


void todo1() {
    if (i>40 || i<=50) {
         i=i*4;
         printf("%d", i);
    } else if (i>30 || i<=40) {
         i=i*3;
         printf("%d", i);
    } else if (i>10 || i<=20) {
         i=i*2;
         printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: ... and [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is not homeworks forum

Comment: `if inserted number is 20 or between 10 and 20` : isn't that the same as `if inserted number is between 10 and 20`

Comment: also learn to use printf: `printf("Enter Number:\t",i);` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips that i'll give to you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    printf("Enter Number:"); // What were /t and i doing here?
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if (i%2) // "!=0" Can be replace by nothing
        printf("%d is an odd number",i); //If you got only one line after a statement, you don't need braces
    else{ // Your function isn't needed since its only called once
        if (i>10 || i<=20)
            i *= 2; // Same as i = i * 2
        if (i>30 || i<=40)// You don't need an else since i doesn't change its value
            i *= 3;
        if (i>40 || i<=50)
            i *= 4;
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

If you still want to use a function, then add a parameter to it, it can't access the `i` variable from the main function:

```
void todo1(int i);
```

Call:

```
todo1(i);
```

Comment: _If you got only one line after a statement, you don't need brackets_ (BTW it's _braces_ not _backets_). Using braces even if there is only one statement, is not necessarily bad practice.

Comment: Thanks, and thats why i said "you don't need" and not "you have to remove"

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the value of variable 'i' to your todo1() function. So, todo1() function is unaware of value of variable 'i' and that's why you stuck in that function.

Make the following changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void todo1 (int);  // declare parameter type,too

int main(){
int i;
printf("Enter Number:\t",i);
scanf("%d",&i);
if (i%2!=0){
printf("%d is an odd number",i);
}
else
{
todo1(i);    // pass value of i to todo1()
}
return 0; 
}


void todo1(int i){   //copy value of variable i
    if (i>40 || i<=50)
    {
         i=i*4;
         printf("%d", i);
    }
         else  if (i>30 || i<=40)
             {
               i=i*3;
               printf("%d", i);
             }
              else if (i>10 || i<=20)
                 {
                     i=i*2;
                     printf("%d", i);
                }
             }
```

As an alternative, if you don't want to pass value of i than declare 'i' as a 'Global Variable'. That'll require only one modification your current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i;   //declare i here, globally

void todo1 ();

int main(){

printf("Enter Number:\t",i);
scanf("%d",&i);
if (i%2!=0){
printf("%d is an odd number",i);
}
else
{
todo1();
}
return 0; 
}


void todo1(){
    if (i>40 || i<=50)
    {
         i=i*4;
         printf("%d", i);
    }
         else  if (i>30 || i<=40)
             {
               i=i*3;
               printf("%d", i);
             }
              else if (i>10 || i<=20)
                 {
                     i=i*2;
                     printf("%d", i);
                }
             }
```

Hope it will help!!